# Prevent form submission according to condtion in ajax using ajax and jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have submit form with php,ajax and jquery.I want to prevent form submission according to the ajax condition.But does not stoppng submit form.Any body give any solution for these issue?
My code is given below

```
   <script>

   function validate_form()
   {
   var sale_type= $('#sale_type').val();
   var cust_name=   $('#cust_name').val();

   if(sale_type=='credit')
    {
      alert("msg"); 
      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'ajx_validation_due_date.php',
      data:'cust_name='+cust_name,
      success: function(msg)
      { 
      alert(msg);
      if(msg==0)
      {
        alert("You cant add sale,Due days is completed");
        preventDefault();
        return false;      
      }

    }
   }); 
  }
  }
  </script>
 <form action="" method="post" name="adFrm" onSubmit="return validate_form()">

 </form>
```

Comment: What's `cust_name`? what's the value of `msg` you're getting..?

Comment: i have cust_name value,i forgot to add it,msg value is 0

Answer (score 0):

Usually ajax is for asynchronous calls.

Use 'async' in ajax call. Script will wait until ajax call completes.

```
     $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: 'ajx_validation_due_date.php',
           data:'cust_name='+cust_name,
           async : false,
           success: function(msg)
           { 
                // Your code
           }
     });
```

Or You can validate the same in your php after submission..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, your code will run further without waiting for the ajax call to finish, returning `undefined`, hence the form submission will happen.

Instead, prevent the default form submission using `event.preventDefault()`, and submit it manually.

```
<form action="" method="post" name="adFrm" onSubmit="validate_form(event)">
```

---

```
 function validate_form(event) {
   event = event || window.event;
   event.preventDefault(); // prevent submission
   var sale_type = $('#sale_type').val();
   if (sale_type == 'credit') {
     alert("msg");
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: 'ajx_validation_due_date.php',
         data: 'cust_name=' + cust_name,
         success: function (msg) {
             alert(msg);
             if (msg == 0) {
                 alert("You cant add sale,Due days is completed");  
                 return false;
             }
             else
                 $("[name='adFrm']")[0].submit(); // submit the form manually upon success

         }
     });
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also do it like this. [SOURCE](http://hayageek.com/jquery-ajax-form-submit/)

```
<form action="" method="post" name="adFrm" id="adFrm" >
</form>


$("#adFrm").submit(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit ,
    // and if you again submit , it won't go through this process again.
    var sale_type = $('#sale_type').val();
    if (sale_type == 'credit') {
        alert("msg");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajx_validation_due_date.php',
            data: 'cust_name=' + cust_name,
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
                if (msg == 0) {
                    alert("You cant add sale,Due days is completed");
                    return false;
                }
                else
                    $("#adFrm").submit(); // note: i have unbinded the submit, so it will simply submit, instead of going through all

            }
        });
    }
});
```